# Merge logs by specific timer error in powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

When I run the below command in `SharePoint PowerShell` I get the below mentioned error

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\LOGS\FarmMergedLog.log" -Overwrite -StartTime "12/06/2016 11:45" - EndTime "12/06/2016 11:50"


PS C:\Users\spadmin> Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\LOGS\FarmMergedLog.log" -Overw
e -StartTime "12/06/2016 11:45" - EndTime "12/06/2016 11:50"
Merge-SPLogFile : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argumen
'-'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Merge-SPLogFile <<<<  -Path "C:\LOGS\FarmMergedLog.log" -Overwrite -StartTi
 "12/06/2016 11:45" - EndTime "12/06/2016 11:50"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Merge-SPLogFile], Paramet
   rBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoin
   .PowerShell.SPCmdletMergeLogFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single dash "-" and a space before `EndTime`.

Use

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\LOGS\FarmMergedLog.log" -Overwrite -StartTime "12/06/2016 11:45" -EndTime "12/06/2016 11:50"
```

This error comes from copying code from the article [Merge-SPLogFile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: yes i copied the code from above technet article thanks

Comment: @adilahmed I did too, and saw the error :)